# make a Dynamically created TableRow to be highlighted on selection

Tags: android, tablerow, android-selector

I am filling a table dynamically with an edit text and image view. I want the whole table row to be highlighted when the table row is pressed:

code:

```
    public void display(News news)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LLParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tableRowParams=new TableRow.LayoutParams (TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
    TableRow TR= new TableRow(this);
    TR.setClickable(true);
    TR.setFocusable(true);
    TR.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    TR.setBackgroundResource(drawable.table1);//set background according to selector
    LinearLayout LL= new LinearLayout(this);
    TR.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
    Table1.addView(TR);
    TR.addView(LL, new TableRow.LayoutParams (TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f));

    //Table Row contains EditText and ImageView
    EditText editText1 =new EditText(this);


    ImageView imgview=new ImageView( this);
    LL.addView(imgview, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,4.0f));
    LL.addView(editText1, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f));
    editText1.setText(news.getTitle()+"\n"+news.getSubtitle());
    editText1.setKeyListener(null);
    editText1.setTextColor(0xff000000);

    editText1.setTextSize(15);

    imgview.setImageDrawable(news.getDr());
    imgview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imgview.setMaxHeight(50);
    imgview.setMaxWidth(50);



}
```

**Drawable/table.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff00ff00"/>
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff00ff00"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#00000000"/>
    <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

i got this exception:

```
10-10 07:02:10.058: E/AndroidRuntime(1879): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/table1.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02001f
```

I would appreciate your help. Please be specific